# Can you change Visual Studio 2022's default browser for Dockerised ASP .NET Core applications?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

When debugging my ASP .NET Core Web API application in Visual Studio 2022, I have the Docker configuration set to launch a browser:

[image]

This browser defaults to Edge. Is there a way to change this, to Firefox for example? That is my browser of choice and I would prefer it to simply open a new tab in an existing instance of that rather than an entirely separate Edge window.

Firefox is set as my default browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it does seem to use the default browser.

This is a new install of Win 11, and I had installed Firefox within the same session as my attempted debugging with it - a reboot seemed to result in VS using it as expected.

The default browser behaviour is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-6.0#debug).

Comment: Looking for a solution for 3 days. Changed to an updated Edge browser and problem solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose a default browser to use with the docker profile but it's not clear how to modify the list of possible browsers or if you can modify the launch settings for those browsers...  anyway, from the debug toolbar menu you'll see the very small drop down menu arrow.  Clicking on that gives you a series of drop down menus that lets you choose a browser.

[image]

Note the "Browse With..." does not work for me. The project rebuilds and nothing happens when I click that.  And "Select Web Browsers..." gives a limited choice of chrome, edge, IE.

Comment: 'Browser With' also builds and then does nothing for me. The joys of Visual Studio :)

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022) says _If the browser you want is not yet installed, install the browser first, and then select it._ so it sounds like you should only have to install a browser for it to show up in the list.  You might need to restart VS and Windows.